Question about the proof that uniform asymptotic stability can be characterized by KL function. (Lemma 4.5 in Nonlinear Systems (3rd) by Khalil)
Lemma 4.5 in Nonlinear Systems (3rd):

Consider the nonautonomous system
\begin{equation}
         \dot{x} = f(t,x) ,
     \end{equation} where $f : [0,\infty) \times D \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is piecewise continuous in $t$ and locally Lipschitz in $x$ on $[0,\infty) \times D$, and $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a domain that
contains the origin $x = 0$. The origin is an equilibrium point for this system at $t = 0$ if
\begin{align*}
         f(t,0) &= 0, & \forall t \geq 0.
     \end{align*}
Lemma 4.5 The equilibrium point $x = 0$ of the foregoing system is uniformly asymptotically stable. $\iff$ There exist a class $\mathcal{KL}$ function $\beta$ and a positive constant $c$, independent of $t_0$, such that
\begin{align*}
             \|{x(t)}\| &\leq \beta (\|{x(t_0)}\|, t- t_0), & \forall t \geq t_0 \geq 0,\; \forall \|{x(t_0)}\| < c.
         \end{align*}
Proof $(\Rightarrow)$ Due to uniform stability, there is a constant $c > 0$ and a $\alpha \in \mathcal{K}$ such that for any $r \in (0,c]$, the solution $x(t)$ satisfies
\begin{align*}
         \|{x(t)}\| &\leq \alpha (\|{x(t_0)}\|) < \alpha (r),  & \forall t \geq t_0 \geq 0,\; \forall \|{x(t_0)}\| < r.
     \end{align*}
In addition, since $x(t)$ uniformly asymptotically approaches the origin, we have that for each $\eta > 0$, there is $T = T(\eta, r) > 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
         \|{x(t)}\| &< \eta  & \forall t \geq t_0 + T (\eta,r), \; \forall \|{x(t_0)}\| < r.
     \end{align*}
Let $\bar{T}(\eta,r) $ be the infimum of all applicable $T(\eta, r)$. The function $\bar{T}(\eta,r) $ is nonnegative and nonincreasing in $\eta$, nondecreasing in $r$, and $\bar{T}(\eta,r) = 0$ for all $\eta \geq \alpha (r)$. Let
\begin{align*}
         W_r (\eta) = \frac{2}{\eta } \int_{\eta/2}^{\eta } \bar{T}(s,r) d{s} + \frac{r }{\eta} \geq \bar{T}(\eta,r) + \frac{r }{\eta}.
    \end{align*}   The function $W_r (\eta)$ is positive and has the following properties:

For each fixed $r$, $W_r (\eta)$ is continuous, strictly decreasing, and $W_r (\eta) \to 0$ as $\eta \to \infty$.
For each fixed $\eta$, $W_r (\eta)$ is strictly increasing in $r$.

Let $U_r = W_r^{-1}$. Then, $U_r$ inherits the foregoing two properties of $W_r$ and $\bar{T}(U_r (s),r) < W_{r} (U_r (s)) = s $ which is from the foregoing inequality. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
         \|{x(t)}\| & \leq U_r (t - t_0), & \forall t \geq t_0, \forall \|{x(t_0)}\| < r.
    \end{align*}
It is clear that
\begin{align*}
         \|{x(t)}\| &\leq \min \left\{\alpha (\|{x(t_0)}\|) , U_r (t- t_0 )\right\}, & \forall t \geq t_0, \forall \|{x(t_0)}\| < r.
 \end{align*}
Thus, define $\beta (r,s) = \min \left\{\alpha(r), U_r (s)\right\}$, as desired.

My questions:

Why $W_r (\eta)$ is strictly decreasing?
Why the inequality
\begin{align*}
        \|{x(t)}\| & \leq U_r (t - t_0), & \forall t \geq t_0, \forall \|{x(t_0)}\| < r
    \end{align*}
hold?

